# Can i use Hidden field on Page_Init Event?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to store selected value in hidden field and use on `Page_Init` Event (Code Behind),
Actually i am able to store selected value in hidden field but not able to get on `Page_Init` event is there any way to achieve it same.

**ASPX**

```
$('#ddlRegion').change(function (e) {
                $('#hdnRegionCode').val(this.value);
             });
```

**.cs**

```
    //location
    if (hdnRegionCode.Value != "")
    {
        ServiceReference1.LOCATION[] location = oClient.GetLocations(hdnRegionCode.Value, "1000", null);
        dgDepots.DataSource = location;
        dgDepots.KeyFieldName = "LocationCode";
        ((GridViewDataComboBoxColumn)dgDepots.Columns["LocationCode"]).PropertiesComboBox.DataSource = location;
    }
```

**Hidden Field**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRegionCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Can any one help me

Thanx

Comment: You probably do not need to use `Page_Init` anyway. What are you doing in there?

Comment: I think you confuse between `Page_Init` and `document.ready` ?

Comment: @VDWWD actually i am binding drop down inside grid view using WebServices on Page_Init event

Comment: @Shree yes may be can you please suggest me on same

Comment: @VDWWD Should i bind drop down on page load ? or where i should bind ? Please help me

Comment: `Page_Load`. In 99.9% of user cases you do not need to be in Init

Comment: @VDWWD so you mean instead of Page_Init i should use Page_Loadd ryt ?

Comment: @VDWWD i tried using Page_Load instead of Page_Init but not able to bind drop down on Page_Load

Comment: is `ddlRegion` a ASP control if it is you don't need to store it's value in a hidden field.

You can bind it using a ObjectDataSource (or similar) and on Page_Load you can bind it first time - on a postback the control will be rebound after the Page_Init. So you can on the postback access the value of `ddlRegion`.

In `Page_Init` the control values have not been bound back to the control objects - so accessing it there it will be empty.

Comment: @SalikRafiq no ddlRegion  is not ASP control its html (Select)

Comment: OK but `#hdnRegionCode` is? If so that you need to change the jQuery to `$('#<%= hdnRegionCode.ClientID %>` and access it in the `Page_Load` or after as in `Page_Init` the field values have not yet been loaded.

Comment: @SalikRafiq thnx sir